# How to initialize an array constant specifying desired indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, constants

What I just want is to initialize a string[] array constant by specifying not only the values, but the indexes they will be attached to.

For example, on:

private static readonly string[] Pets = new string[] {"Bulldog", "GreyHound"};

I would like to state that BullDog corresponds to index 29 and GreyHound to 5 (Like php :) )

Any suggestion?

Cheers,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have some flexibility in terms of your data structure, it would be more efficient to use a `Dictionary<int, string>` instead of an array for this behavior.

Example (if you are using C# 3 or above):

```
var pets = new Dictionary<int, string> {
    { 29, "Bulldog" },
    { 5, "Greyhound" }
};
Console.WriteLine(pets[5]);
```

Same example for legacy applications:

```
Dictionary<int, string> pets = new Dictionary<int, string>();
pets[29] = "Bulldog";
pets[5] = "Greyhound";
Console.WriteLine(pets[5]);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, finally I implemented your solution. I used System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> too.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you don't want an array, but a `Dictionary<int, string>` instead, which could be initialized like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> pets = 
    new Dictionary<int, string> {
    { 29, "Bulldog" },
    { 5, "Greyhound" }
};
```

(Note that this *collection initializer* syntax was only added in C# 3. If you're using an older version you'll have to call `Add` or the indexer explicitly multiple times.)

You can access a dictionary via its *indexer* which looks like array access:

```
string x = pets[29];
pets[10] = "Goldfish";
```

Comment: +1 - this is the only answer that shows creation and initialization in the same line, although other answers are generally correct.  You beat me to as usual Jon ;)

Comment: I changed my answer to use an initializer since I agree with your comment.  Also, there's a small typo (: instead of ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want is possible in C# when declaring arrays.

Besides using a `Dictionary` as others have suggested, you could try using an enumeration instead, with values corresponding to your specific array indices and descriptions (using the `Description` attribute) corresponding to the string values.

```
private enum Pets
{
   [Description("GreyHound")]
   Greyhound = 5,
   [Description("Bulldog")]
   Bulldog = 29
}
```

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but it's possible to use an array initializer to assign null to everything except the 5th and 29th elements.  If I saw that in the wild though, I might shoot the perpetrator :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I agree with everyone that a `Dictionary` is probably more appropriate. But you can write a little method to pull off what you want:

```
public static T[] CreateArray<T>(params Tuple<int, T>[] values)
{
    var sortedValues = values.OrderBy(t => t.Item1);

    T[] array = new T[sortedValues.Last().Item1 + 1];

    foreach(var value in sortedValues)
    {
        array[value.Item1] = value.Item2;
    }

    return array;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
string[] myArray = CreateArray(new Tuple<int, string>(34, "cat"), new Tuple<int, string>(12, "dog"));
```

If C# receives the syntactic sugar for `Tuple` that many people seem to want, this would get a tad cleaner looking.

Is this a good idea? Almost certainly not, but I'll leave that for the OP to judge.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a string array, but instead a `Dictionary`.

Take a look at [link text](http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys), there's a fine example there (which I adapted here):

```
Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        d.Add(2, "cat");
        d.Add(1, "dog");
        d.Add(0, "llama");
        d.Add(-1, "iguana");
```

Comment: The other answers are more intuitive for use, with `int` being the key and `string` being the value. This answer assumes you know the values rather than the desired "index" positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that in the initializer, you need to first specify the size of the array and then add items at specific locations.

```
private static readonly string[] Pets = new string[42];
```

and then in a static constructor you insert your items.

```
private static MyClass
{
    Pets[29] = "Bulldog";
    Pets[5] = "Greyhound";
}
```

But as other have suggested: use the `Dictionary<int, string>`.